# Sometimes the using namespace std; is inside main or other functions?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Usually when someone declares `using namespace std;` (I know that it is a [bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)), They should declare it like that:

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Some code here...
    return 0;
}
```

But it is a completely different story here. The `using namespace std;` is sometimes located in `int main()` (Code 1.12), Maybe in a function named Hello (Code 1.13):

*Code 1.12*

```
# include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    // Some code after namespace...
    return 0;
}
```

*Code 1.13*

```
# include <iostream>

void Hello()
{
    using namespace std;
    // Some code again...
}

int main() // Adding up main just to ensure there are no errors
{
    return 0;
}
```

Why do they need to initialize `using namespace std;`, in a function or in function `main`?

Comment: `using namespace std;` is bad in headers. Thats what is explained in the Q&A you link. Using it elsewhere is fine. Your question is somewhat unclear. Who is "they" ? in your examples the line can be removed without consequences. Its the same as elsewhere, it introduces all names from `std` such that you need to prepend every name with `std::`

Comment: No idea, but just remove the using namespace std, and type std:: where needed. Just learn the good habit :) Just NEVER use "using namespace" in a header.

Comment: I'm with @pepijn.  There's a reason why `std` is nice and short :)

Comment: You're asking why? Do you know what that line does? Because if you do, that's why.

Comment: It would be best if you stop doing `using namespace std;` in any case. Many coding standards forbids that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `using` for namespaces statement pulls in all symbols from the namespace into the current scope.

If you do it in the global namespace scope then all symbols from the `std` namespace would be available in the global (`::`) namespace. But only for the current [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

If you do `using` inside the function, or even a nested block inside a function, then the symbols from `std` would only be pulled into that (more narrow) scope.

---

Lets take your last example, and add some stuff to it:

```
#include <iostream>

void Hello()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Hello\n";  // Valid, cout is in the current scope
}

int main()
{
    cout << "World\n";  // Not valid, there's no cout symbol in the current scope
}
```

Here `cout` is available only inside the `Hello` function, because that's where you added `std::cout` to the functions scope.

In the `main` function there's no such symbol `cout`.

Comment: What does If you you means?

Comment: @user19552329 typo; fixed.

Comment: That means it is only valid for that specific scope, but not valid for others (if not declared).